# Unable to load delphi 7 project because of tlib70.bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a code which generated dll, but at the time of loading that project I am getting IDE exception as mentioned below :

> Error loading type library/dll.

Its type is `EInternalTypeLibraryException`.

and exact message is:

> An error occurred while referencing a user defined type. This may be caused by a missing or unregistered type library.

Comment: `tlib70.bpl` should be in your Delphi 7 installation's `bin` folder. If it's not, or it's not registered with the system, your Delphi installation is broken and you'll need to reinstall it.

Comment: @Ken White - Thanks Ken. It exists there in bin folder, also if I compile that project from command line it gets compiled, only issue while opening it from Delphi IDE.

Comment: @KenWhite tlib70.bpl is a Delphi compiled package. It's not a COM module and doesn't support COM self-registration.

Comment: @Trupti Tell us more about your project. What aspect of your project triggers this IDE error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am trying to open a .dpr file, which may be loading some system files internally but it fails and raises above exception. I could find above information from Eureka log tool installed at that machine. It looks like tlib70.bpl is referring to **System.pas** and its procedure `_RaiseExcept` is raising this error. what else I can check?

Comment: Next step is to isolate the problem. Create a brand new project, save and open that. Does that raise the error? If not, work out what aspect of the problem project is required to trigger the fault.

Comment: You can also try to create a new blank project and trying to load bpl dynamically using LoadPackage . 
See if generates error.

Comment: Do you have the code for this BPL? 
If yes, check the code of the INITIALIZATION and FINALIZATION sections to search errors.